# PlayFramework set javascript source path from sbt.

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a PlayFramework project that used sbt as a build tool. 
Sbt searching for javascript assets (jsx and js files) into the 
following directory:

```
/project/name/directory/app/assets/javascripts
```

I want this to be changed from build sbt but I cannot find 
what settings to change. (I'm sbt lamer)

Comment: What do you want to change it to? Basically, the app/assets part is configurable in SBT. The rest depends on your project structure

Comment: "Basically, the app/assets part is configurable in SBT. ".  I will be very thankful for example. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the `app/assets` part is configurable in SBT by changing the `sourceDirectory in Assets` setting. The rest depends on your project structure.

By default the setting is set to:

```
sourceDirectory in Assets := (sourceDirectory in Compile).value / "assets"
```

You could change it to `path/to/assets` by overriding this in your `build.sbt`. For example:

```
sourceDirectories in Assets := new File("path/to/assets")
```

This would tell sbt-web to look for assets in the `path/to/assets` directory in you project's root directory.

Note that you might also have to account for the test assets as well. In case you're using them, you'll have to override the `sourceDirectories in TestAssets` setting in the same fashion.